# Bluemix sql database recovery

Tags: sql, schema, ibm-cloud, recovery, user-defined

When I removed my app from the Bluemix dashboard, it removed the associated SQL db as well. I have a script that creates new tables/indexes with our schema name but the free version of SQL database does not support user-defined schema names. The problem is in our code, we need to have our schema name rather than `user***` schema name.

Does Bluemix still offer small version of SQL database ? If not, is there a way to recover our database, or is there a way I can rename the `user***` schema created by the free version to the name I want?

Comment: I cannot answer the recovery question off-hand. However, it was announced on the Bluemix status page that the SQL Database small service was discontinued on September 1, 2015. Here was the announcement:

"Starting September 1, 2015, new SQL Database small instances cannot be added. To improve our SQL Database services, new service architecture will deliver better scalability and security options. As a result, we will sunset the SQL Database Small Plan in favor of our SQL Database Free, SQL Database Premium, Compose PostgreSQL plans." A subject matter expert can respond to the recovery part.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use a user defined schema name. Anyway as a general rule in development, properties like schema name or connection properties should be parametric, in order to have more flexibility in your solution. 
What is preventing to have your SQL to be adapted to the new db instance? You could have a simple script which load it and run on the instance, without any need to use an hardcoded schema name